# getting the right Call when applying lm (or other models) to a list of formulas

Tags: r

I often want to run a list of models, like so:

```
data(mtcars)
ms <- lapply(list(
      mpg ~ disp
    , mpg ~ hp
    ), lm, data=mtcars
```

I'd then like to be able to extract the call from these models, like so:

```
lapply(ms, getCall)
```

But I get this:

```
[[1]]
FUN(formula = X[[1L]], data = ..1)
[[2]]
FUN(formula = X[[2L]], data = ..1)
```

How can I get this:

```
[[1]]
lm(formula = mpg ~ disp, data=mtcars)
[[2]]
lm(formula = mpg ~ hp, data=mtcars)
```

(I figured out I could get it by just making a list of the models, like this:

```
ms <- list(
      lm(mpg ~ disp, data=mtcars)
    , lm(mpg ~ hp, data=mtcars)
    )
```

But I'd prefer to avoid the repetition.

I have a sense that this has to do with evaluating the formula in the right environment, but I don't know how to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think lapply is invoking `lm` under a different name, maybe try this:

```
data(mtcars)
ms <- lapply(list(
      mpg ~ disp
    , mpg ~ hp
    ), function(x) lm(x, data=mtcars) )
```

EDIT:

We'll have to mess with `substitute` too then:

```
data(mtcars)
f <- function(x) {z <- x; eval(substitute(lm(z, data=mtcars))) }
ms <- lapply(list(
      mpg ~ disp
    , mpg ~ hp
    ), f)

R>
R>ms
[[1]]

Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ disp, data = mtcars)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)         disp  
29.59985476  -0.04121512  


[[2]]

Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ hp, data = mtcars)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           hp  
30.09886054  -0.06822828
```

Comment: This is closer, but the now the formula is replaced by 'x', eg: `lm(formula = x, data = mtcars)`

Comment: The edited version with `eval` and `substitute` does exactly what I need.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is an issue with the scoping rules of `lapply` and non-standard evaluation in `lm`. However, you can get around it by creating a base model, and using `update` in an `lapply` call:

```
tlm <- lm(data=mtcars)
lapply(list(mpg~disp,mpg~hp), update, object=tlm)
[[1]]

Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ disp, data = mtcars)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)         disp  
   29.59985     -0.04122  


[[2]]

Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ hp, data = mtcars)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           hp  
   30.09886     -0.06823
```